# Passing javascript variable to servlet

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, servlets, struts

How can I pass a var from javascript to a servlet. Yes I know you can use getParameter on the servlet side, but I first need to do some javascript stuff then from there it need to pass that new variable to servlet.

See my Javascript example:

```
function openBrWindowAndSubmit() { 

  var textBodyValue = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("textBody").value);
  alert(textBodyValue); //returns empty
  document.forms[0].submit();

  var textBodyValue = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("textBody").value);
  alert(textBodyValue); //works

}
```

As you can see in above example the first "alert" block returns empty, but the second one returns the correct encoded value because the document.forms[0].submit is already called. So is there a way I can get the second variable "textBodyValue" (which is outside of document.forms[0].submit) to the servlet? I'm calling this at the servlet side:

```
String test = req.getParameter("textBody");
```

Here's the JSP inside a form tag which calls the function on click:

```
 <textarea id="textBody" name="textBody"></textarea>        
 <input type="button" onClick="openBrWindowAndSubmit();" value="Click Here to Preview Email">
```

Is there any workaround to this problem?

I've been trying to change the javascript function to:

```
function openBrWindowAndSubmit() { //v2.0

  document.forms[0].target = "_blank";
  document.getElementById("action").value = "view_template";
  var textBodyValue = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("textBody").value);
  alert(textBodyValue);
  document.forms[0].submit();

  var textBodyValue = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("textBody").value);
  alert(textBodyValue);

  $.ajax({
      url: 'http://localhost:8080/restricted/comm/Email',
      data: textBodyValue,
    //  processData: false,
    //  contentType: false,
      type: 'POST',
      success: function(data){
        alert(data);
      }
    }); 
}
```

Can this work? i'm getting an undefined error when reaching the $ajax tag?

Comment: You could use a library like jQuery and override the submitfunction and then manually make a AJAX Post.

Comment: Could you please provide me with an example?

Comment: You have to include jquery in your .js file:<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.templates/beta1/jquery.tmpl.js"></script>

Comment: Thanks! I've added this and made error go away, but that ajax is not passing the new data to the servlet

Comment: data: textBodyValue, i dont think that this will work. Try var dataToSend = { textBodyValue : encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("textBody").value)}; and then in your $.ajax data : dataToSend,

Answer (score 0):

As an idea. Dont know if its correct ;) but you can check it at the jQuery api page.

```
$('#idOfTheForm').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    data = { key : val , key2 : val2 };
    $.ajax({
    type: "post",
    data: data,
    url : "",
    success : function(response){
                  console.log("return code was 200");    
               },
    error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                  console.log(errorThrown);
            }
    });
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Hi,Thanks but this is not right, can you try provide example as from my code?

Comment: @user2319262 This is your job. Maybe you can try yourself and update your question including error messages and so on

Comment: Thanks, Ive been trying to change the javascript function. Please see at my question above

Comment: what is your jsp page you are going to submit your request in your ajax call..?  i think you can't use "http://localhost:8080/restricted/comm/Email" in the url...

Comment: the page is http://localhost:8080/restricted/comm/Email , thats the servlet page where the new Var value needs to be send to